# Apply XSLT tags that aren't there

Tags: xslt, attributes, latex

I am trying to convert an XML document into LaTeX using XSLT. I have two tags `<lin>` and `<gra>` which, roughly speaking, correspond to a paragraph and a choice of text size, respectively. However, in the case where `<lin>` is run from within a `<blok ryk="lyrik">` tag, I want `<lin>` to be applied identically to `<lin ryk="lang"><gra str="-1">`. I know I could just copy the definition of the latter, but for several reasons, the mentioned solution is to be preferred. I felt very lucky and decided to try the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
<xsl:apply-templates/>
\end{document}

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lin[@ryk='lang']"><!--
-->{\parindent=3em <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>}
</xsl:text><!--
--></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gra[@str='-1']">{\small <xsl:apply-templates/>}</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="blok[@ryk='lyrik']/lin" priority="7">
<lin ryk="lang"><gra str="-1">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</gra></lin>
</xsl:template>
```

This did not work, since the `<lin ryk="lang"><gra str="-1">` code is completely ignored. It was perhaps a bit optimistic to hope that you could just simply write out the code this way. But then what *should* I have done? Here is a piece of example XML code to apply it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blok ryk="lyrik">
<lin>Attributes are red.</lin>
<lin>Tags are blue.</lin>
<lin>Text is black.</lin>
<lin>Please help my code compute.</lin>
</blok>
```

The output I get is simply the same without the tags.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
Attributes are red.
Tags are blue.
Text is black.
Please help my code compute.
\end{document}
```

What I want is the following:

```
{\small\parindent=3em Attributes are red.}
{\small\parindent=3em  Tags are blue.}
{\small\parindent=3em  Text is black.}
{\small\parindent=3em  Please help my code compute.}}
```

P.S. If someone uses `<xsl:copy>` in the solution, please *explain to me what that tag really does*. I've read countless tutorials and examples and still don't really get it.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the output you expect in this case? Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned, it just removes the tags and does nothing else. I have now added the output. :-)

Comment: Also, the output that you actually want too, would help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to create a variable

`<xsl:template match="blok[@ryk='lyrik']/lin" priority="7">
<xsl:variable name="l1">
 <lin ryk="lang"><gra str="-1"> <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/> </gra></lin> 
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$l1/node()"/>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why it worked, but it did. Thank you! :-)