# Parse XML tags that aren't there

Tags: xml, xslt, latex

This question is a follow-up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640254/apply-xslt-tags-that-arent-there). I am writing an XSLT script to convert XML to LaTeX. An example XML document is seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lin ryk="ind">A paragraph with short indentation.</lin>
<lin ryk="ind2">A paragraph with long indentation.</lin>

<blok ryk="udspark">
<lin>
<tab ryk="ind">Text on the left.</tab>
<tab>Text on the right.</tab>
</lin>
</blok>
```

Long story short, the `<blok ryk="udspark">` tag writes a paragraph with the content of the first `<tag>`on the left and the content of the second `<tag>` on the right, separated by space (this is done in LaTeX by separating them with the command `\hfill`). In other words, I want to parse the `<blok ryk="udspark">`tag above *as if* it were actually written

```
<lin ryk="ind">Text on the left.\hfill Text on the right.</lin>
```

Notice that value `"ind"` of the `@ryk` attribute of the first tab is parsed to the `<lin>`.In general, for any values of `X`, I want

```
<blok ryk="udspark">
<lin>
<tab ryk="X">Text on the left.</tab>
<tab>Text on the right.</tab>
</lin>
</blok>
```

to be parsed as

```
<lin ryk="X">Text on the left.\hfill Text on the right.</lin>
```

Because of the question I linked to earlier, I tried the following code (if you don't know LaTeX, don't worry too much about the definitions of the `<lin>` tags. They do note matter much; what matters is `<blok ryk="udspark">`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

<xsl:apply-templates/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lin[@ryk='ind']">
\indent <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lin[@ryk='ind2']">
\hangpara{2\parindent}{-1}{<xsl:apply-templates/>}<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="blok[@ryk='udspark']">
<xsl:variable name="l2">
<lin ryk="lin/tab[1]/@ryk">
<xsl:copy-of select="node()/lin/tab[1]"/>\hfill <xsl:copy-of select="node()/lin/tab[2]"/></lin>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$l2/node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, it doesn't work! The only thing that appears is `\hfill`, nothing else.

Note that in my real document, `X` can take *far* (!!!) more values than above. That is why I want to reuse the XSLT code for the `<lin>` tags instead of just programming it all again in the code for the `<blok ryk="udspark">` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<lin ryk="lin/tab[1]/@ryk">` you want `<lin ryk="{lin/tab[1]/@ryk}">` which would populate the attribute with the result of the XPath expression in curly braces.

Then for the content instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="node()/lin/tab[1]"/>\hfill <xsl:copy-of select="node()/lin/tab[2]"/></lin>` I think you want `<xsl:value-of select="lin/tab[1]"/>\hfill <xsl:value-of select="lin/tab[2]"/></lin>`.

So the complete code would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

<xsl:apply-templates/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lin[@ryk='ind']">
\indent <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lin[@ryk='ind2']">
\hangpara{2\parindent}{-1}{<xsl:apply-templates/>}<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="blok[@ryk='udspark' and lin/tab/@ryk]">
<xsl:variable name="l2">
<lin ryk="{lin/tab[1]/@ryk}">
<xsl:value-of select="lin/tab[1]"/>\hfill <xsl:value-of select="lin/tab[2]"/></lin>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$l2/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms

```
<root>
<lin ryk="ind">A paragraph with short indentation.</lin>
<lin ryk="ind2">A paragraph with long indentation.</lin>

<blok ryk="udspark">
<lin>
<tab ryk="ind">Text on the left.</tab>
<tab>Text on the right.</tab>
</lin>
</blok>
</root>
```

into

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}



\indent A paragraph with short indentation.


\hangpara{2\parindent}{-1}{A paragraph with long indentation.}



\indent Text on the left.\hfill Text on the right.
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! BTW, another question: If I want to get the value of the `<tab>`s, but also to *apply all children* of it, how can I do that?

Comment: In the samples you have shown, the `tab` elements don't have child elements. If they have and you need to process them with matching templates, then I guess instead of the `<xsl:value-of select="lin/tab[1]"/>\hfill <xsl:value-of select="lin/tab[2]"/>` you want to use `<xsl:copy-of select="lin/tab[1]/node()"/>\hfill <xsl:copy-of select="lin/tab[2]/node()"/>`, that would copy an child nodes and later on the processing of the variable would then allow you to have matching templates applied.